# Are there donkeys in the Star Wars universe?

Tags: star-wars, animals

Inspired by a now-deleted comment from @WadCheber on [another question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/102000/how-to-pronounce-mos-eisley)...

**Are there donkeys in the Star Wars universe?** If not, what's the closest equivalent?

<sub>Might look like a silly question, but [there](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/86382/are-there-cats-or-creatures-similar-to-cats-in-the-star-wars-universe) are [precedents](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/94838/food-in-the-star-wars-universe).</sub>

> Another Star Wars question from the guy who's [never seen Star Wars](http://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/b00hcr67)! :-O

Comment: Suggestions on what to do with someone who's never seen Star Wars, if *forcing them to ride a donkey backwards into the desert with a bucket on their head* is out of the question, will also be welcome.

Comment: http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Snack-donkey

Comment: @Richard Think this question is worth keeping around? I'm leaning towards deleting it...

Comment: Don't delete it; it's questions like this that make this site quirky!  You've got my +1

Comment: The question is: are there any mules... Seriously if there are mules, because they're the offspring of donkeys and horses, that would *prove* there are donkeys - assuming genetics work the same in SW as they do here on Eath

Comment: There is one big ass. He's responsible for the prequel trilogy.

Comment: If there's a Pleasure Island and a little wooden boy in the Star Wars universe, there's bound to be donkeys.

Comment: Best question ever.

Comment: @JamesMcLeod and his name is mace windu

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no canon instances of donkeys showing up in any *Star Wars* works.

However, "[Snack-donkeys](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Snack-donkey)" are mentioned in the non-canon book *[Monsters and Aliens from George Lucas](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Monsters_and_Aliens_from_George_Lucas)*.

Additionally, there are [horses and ponies](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Horse) in the Legends continuity. There were also [many animals similar to horses](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Equine).

Comment: I still don't fully understand the difference between horses and ponies.  I thought ponies were just small horses, but apparently some ponies never become horses, even though the species is obviously "horse".

Comment: Especially Stone Poneys.

Answer (score 3):

I'll try to answer, anyway. There are no donkeys in Star Wars universe. But here are other beasts of burden, as donkeys on Earth are used primarily for carriage on undeveloped or some still developing countries.

[Dewback](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Dewback)
[Eopie](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Eopie)
[Fambaa](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Fambaa)
[Ronto](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Ronto)
[Tauntaun](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Tauntaun)
[Bantha](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Bantha)

Among these, Eopie would be the closest equivalent. Quadruped and somewhat "thin" of shape, mostly-humanoid height.

Comment: How does this prove that donkeys don't exist?

Comment: Because if I were George Lucas or any other author of Star Wars, I would avoid naming a creature I just came up with as "donkey", or "Alderaanian mountain donkey", or "Tatooine Sand Donkey" or "Sullustan Procedural Donkey". How about that? ...Fun aside, none of the published Star Wars guides list donkeys in existence, so it's safe to presume that they really don't exist.

Comment: “none of the published Star Wars guides list donkeys in existence, so it's safe to presume that they really don't exist” no potential to be taken out of context there, huh?